# Links in site running on IIS don't redirect correctly

Tags: iis-7

In IIS I have a site created that is pointing to inetpub/wwwroot. I then have an application called V3 created under this site, but whose directory is located elsewhere. From IIS I browse to this application and it works fine. Then, however, if I click a link that should navigate to the page called test, the redirect attempts to go to localhost/test instead of localhost/V3/test. An error occurs.

How can I get the links to redirect correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to add a `~` to the path of the links. If you have `<a href="/test">foobar</a>` try making it `<a href="~/test">foobar</a>`. `~` makes it relative to the root of the application instead of the root of the domain.